# Line Chart using Count in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, data-visualization, linechart

| company | Month_Yr | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Belmawa | Apr 2020 | 15 |
| 2 Belmawa | Apr 2021 | 28 |
| 3 Belmawa | Aug 2020 | 15 |
| 4 Belmawa | Dec 2020 | 18 |
| 5 Belmawa | Feb 2020 | 15 |
| 6 Belmawa | Feb 2021 | 27 |
| 7 Belmawa | Jan 2020 | 15 |
| 8 Belmawa | Jan 2021 | 23 |
| 9 Belmawa | Jul 2020 | 21 |
| 10 Belmawa | Jun 2020 | 20 |

the table above is a result from this code:`df1 %>% group_by(company, Month_Yr) %>% summarize(count=n())`
how can i use the month year as a x axis, the count as x axis and the company as a group for line chart? (assume the company has 3 different companies and the x axis to be just 4 specific month)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

### Data

```
df <-
tibble::tribble(
      ~company,  ~month_year, ~count,
   "Belmawa", "Apr 2020",    15L,
   "Belmawa", "Apr 2021",    28L,
   "Belmawa", "Aug 2020",    15L,
   "Belmawa", "Dec 2020",    18L,
   "Belmawa", "Feb 2020",    15L,
   "Belmawa", "Feb 2021",    27L,
   "Belmawa", "Jan 2020",    15L,
   "Belmawa", "Jan 2021",    23L,
   "Belmawa", "Jul 2020",    21L,
   "Belmawa", "Jun 2020",    20L
  ) %>% 
  # Transforming month_year from character to date 
  mutate(
    month_year = mdy(month_year)
  )
```

### Plot code

```
df %>% 
  # Defining aesthetics
  ggplot(aes(x = month_year,y = count, col = company))+
  geom_line()
```

#### Plot output

[image]